# Scrollview only scrollable inside parent view react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've got a ScrollView nested in an absolute positioned View that is bigger then it's parent. The scrolling works fine if I press inside that parent, but when I go outside it, it's not handling the touches. How can I get around this?

[image]
I can't scroll if I touch the screen below the green line.

Code to reproduce:

```
<View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center"}}>
  <View style={{width: "80%", height: 150, borderWidth: 1}}>
    <View style={{position: 'absolute', height: 400, width: "80%", backgroundColor: "green", alignSelf: "center"}}>
    <ScrollView>
    <View style={{height: 200, backgroundColor: "red"}} />
    <View style={{height: 200, backgroundColor: "blue"}} />
    <View style={{height: 200, backgroundColor: "yellow"}} />
    </ScrollView>
    </View>
  </View>
</View>
```

Expo Snack: https://snack.expo.dev/uV88qpP7f (Happens on android)

Comment: Can you add your code to the question?

Comment: wrap into same height to parent. Replace <View style={{width: "80%",height: 400, borderWidth: 1}}> to top two View tag.

Comment: But I want it to overlap the box

Comment: It's a known issue with Android btw https://reactnative.dev/docs/handling-touches#known-issues the github issue linked has some workarounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Demo

https://snack.expo.dev/bsHCCB1_l

Try declaring your `Box` above the scroll view otherwise the touch area below `Box` won't work

`ScrollView` with Position absolute should be below to Box to make touch in work

## Code

```
import { View,ScrollView } from 'react-native';

const Box=()=>{
  return <View style={{ height: 150, borderWidth: 1}} />
}
const DropDown=()=>{
  return (
    <View style={{position: 'absolute', height: 400, width: "80%", backgroundColor: "green", alignSelf: "center"}}>
      <ScrollView>
      <View style={{height: 200, backgroundColor: "red"}} />
      <View style={{height: 200, backgroundColor: "blue"}} />
      <View style={{height: 200, backgroundColor: "yellow"}} />
      </ScrollView>
     </View>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center"}}>
      <View style={{width: "80%"}}>

        <Box />

        <DropDown /> 

      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is with your approach to design. You can achieve the desire functionality with same design by following code.

```
<View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center"}}>
  <View style={{width: "80%"}}>
    <View style={{ height: 150, borderWidth: 1}}/>
    <View style={{position: 'absolute', height: 400, width: "80%", backgroundColor: "green", alignSelf: "center"}}>
    <ScrollView>
    <View style={{height: 200, backgroundColor: "red"}} />
    <View style={{height: 200, backgroundColor: "blue"}} />
    <View style={{height: 200, backgroundColor: "yellow"}} />
    </ScrollView>
    </View>
  </View>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way I found was to move the ScrollView outside of the card container and get the top position of the ScrollView by calculating the area of the button and container it's supposed to be relating to. Sort of how tooltips often function.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Pressable,
  Text,
  ScrollView,
  FlatList,
} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { Feather } from '@expo/vector-icons';

const data = [
  {
    color: 'red',
  },
  {
    color: 'blue',
  },
  {
    color: 'orange',
  },
  {
    color: 'green',
  },
  {
    color: 'pink',
  },
];

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('Press me!');
  const [heightOfButton, setHeightOfButton] = useState(0);
  const [heightOfContainer, setHeightOfContainer] = useState(0);
  const [shouldShow, setShouldShow] = useState(true);
  // android handles the padding a bit strange but I feel like this is close to what you're looking for.
  const scrollPosition = heightOfContainer + 12 + heightOfButton

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View
        onLayout={(e) =>
          setHeightOfContainer(e.nativeEvent.layout.y)
        }
        style={styles.card}>
        <Pressable
          onLayout={(e) =>
            setHeightOfButton(e.nativeEvent.layout.height)
          }
          onPress={() => setShouldShow(true)}
          style={styles.button}>
          <Text>{value}</Text>
          <Feather name="chevron-down" size={24} />
        </Pressable>
      </View>
      {shouldShow ? (
        <FlatList
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            top: scrollPosition,
            height: 400,
            width: '80%',
            backgroundColor: 'green',
            alignSelf: 'center',
          }}
          data={data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Pressable
              onPress={() => {
                setValue(item.color);
                setShouldShow(false);
              }}
              style={{ height: 200, backgroundColor: item.color }}
            />
          )}
        />
      ) : null}
      {/*<ScrollView 
          style={{ 
            position: 'absolute',
            bottom: height,
            height: 400, 
            width: "80%", 
            backgroundColor: "green", 
            alignSelf: "center"
          }}>
        <View style={{height: 200, backgroundColor: "red"}} />
        <View style={{height: 200, backgroundColor: "blue"}} />
        <View style={{height: 200, backgroundColor: "yellow"}} />
        </ScrollView> */}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
    padding: 8,
  },
  card: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    height: '30%',
    borderRadius: 8,
    padding: 12,
  },
  button: {
    width: '100%',
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderRadius: 8,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 12,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
});
```

I moved your example to a FlatList as it seems like that was what you were hoping to do in the example.

Here's the snack https://snack.expo.dev/@corywritescode/frowning-carrot

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that might be a workaround, but what I'd like to archieve is to create a  Dropdown-component and use that inside a dialog... Is there any way to archieve this?

Comment: @JaRoMaster, I don't think so. I think the way android renders the view hierarchy there's not a clear way to tell it to "ignore certain parts of a view container". I'm not sure the technical side of it but you need to be able to have the scrollview sitting on top of the other views to use it like you are trying to and it doesn't seem like android allows for such things.

Comment: Seems like @Muhammed Numan's answer works

Answer (score -1):

You can do this

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default function App() {
const customHeight = 400; //change this based on your needs


return (
<View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center"}}>
  <View style={{width: "80%", height: 150, borderWidth: 1}}>
    <View style={{position: 'absolute', height: customHeight, width: "80%", backgroundColor: "green", alignSelf: "center"}}>
    <ScrollView style={{backgroundColor: "grey", height: 600}}>
    <View style={{height: 200, backgroundColor: "red"}} />
    <View style={{height: 200, backgroundColor: "blue"}} />
    <View style={{height: 200, backgroundColor: "yellow"}} />
    </ScrollView>
    </View>
  </View>
</View>
);
}
```

Comment: First of all: What did you change exactly except creating a varaible for the heiight?
This solution is still not solving the problem: You still can't scroll if you start the touch outside the box in the background

Comment: I thought your problem was that view you have wouldn't scroll if you scroll outside of your box, right? the code I wrote there is actually working. you should adjust your height based on the View outside of the Scroll View, not the Scroll View itself

Comment: When I paste the code you sent into the expo snack, I still have the same problem on android: When I start the touch for the scrolling outside of the box in the background, I cant scroll. The scrolling only works if I start the touch inside the box.

Answer (score -3):

Absolute position style causes this problem. I just remove it and set new style above.

```html
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center"}}>
      <View style={{width: "80%", height: 150, borderWidth: 1, backgroundColor: "green"}}>
        <ScrollView>
        <View style={{height: 70, backgroundColor: "red"}} />
        <View style={{height: 70, backgroundColor: "blue"}} />
        <View style={{height: 70, backgroundColor: "yellow"}} />
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Please edit your answer to provide clarification, don't provide it in the comments.